# either headed or heading

Tags: word-choice, tense

> While locust swarms continue to plague African countries, for now, the outbreak has tapered down in India with swarms **headed** back towards Sindh and Balochistan.

I think here **headed** is grammatically wrong as the sentence is framed in the present tense so **heading** should be used

Comment: It's fine. There's no reason why you can't mix tenses within a sentence. ✔ *It **is** raining in London even though it **stopped** raining in Cambridge hours ago.* It's just that mixing tenses in the wrong way can result in something strange. ✘ *I **will run** to the store and **picked up** groceries.*

Comment: @JasonBassford given that "headed back towards Sindh" is a participial phrase, it's more about mood (active/passive) rather than tense (past/present).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/headed), it is possible to use **headed** as an adjective meaning going in a particular direction. it is unclear why the past/passive participle should be used in this way, when you would expect a present/active participle.

The more common way of expressing this is to use the word **going**. Here is an Ngram Graph that shows that **headed** and **heading** only first arose in [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were%20heading%20back%2Cwere%20headed%20back%2Cwere%20going%20back&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20heading%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20headed%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20going%20back%3B%2Cc0) around 1900, and their popularity only took off in the 1970s.

This Ngram Graph shows a similar trend in [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were%20heading%20back%2Cwere%20headed%20back%2Cwere%20going%20back&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20heading%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20headed%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20going%20back%3B%2Cc0), although it is noticeable that **headed** is significantly less common in British English than in American English.

Answer (score 1):

"be heading..." is a simple application of the verb "head" in present participle.

"be headed..." can be understood as either an idiom of the passive form, or the use of an adjective based on the past participle.  In either case, the meaning is not the natural meaning of the passive but the same as "heading". You can't generalise from this to other past participles.